# WPF Hotkey one key, no modifiers keys

Tags: wpf, global, modifiers

can I made WPF application with one key hotkey? Everywhere is tutorial to make hotkeys with modifiers, like: [Alt]+[X]. For example I need made global hotkey [F9].
How can I do that in C# .NET 4.5 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can.  When you create your command object, one of the things you can pass is an `InputGestureCollection`, which contains a list of objects that descend from the `InputGesture` class.  One of these classes is the `KeyGesture` class, which defines the specific key sequence used to use to activate the command.

One of the properties of the `KeyGesture` class is the [`Key` property, of type `Key`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.input.key).  This is an enumeration of key values.  The one you want is `Key.F9`.

To create the Command, you'd do something like this:

```
InputGestureCollection myCommandGestures = new InputGesturecollection();
myCommandGestures.Add( new KeyGesture( Key.F9 );
RoutedCommand MyCommand = new RoutedCommand( "MyCommand", typeof( MyViewModelClass ), myCommandGestures );
```

**EDIT**

The above works within WPF only.  If you want a global hot key, you'll have to call the Win32 `RegisterHotKey` function.  [The answer to this question on the Visual Studio forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/87d66b1c-330c-42fe-8a40-81f82012575c/background-hotkeys-wpf?forum=wpf) contains a link to an example of how to do that.

I'm not sure if you will have to do both or just call the `RegisterHotKey` function to register your hot key.

Comment: Thanks you it is helpfully for now :) If I got one hotkey now, can I register it as global hotkey ? I need catch F9 from every window when my application is minimized to tray.